# Part of a code in Razor view isn't rendered

Tags: asp.net-mvc, razor

Why in the following Razor markup

```
@foreach (var item in Model) {
    <tr>
        <td>@Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.IncidentId)</td>
        ...
        <td>
            @Html.ActionLink("View", "View", new { id = item.IncidentId })
            @Html.ActionLink("Edit", "Edit", new { id = item.IncidentId })
            @{
            if (User.IsInRole("Manager"))
            {
                Html.ActionLink("Remove", "Remove", new {id = item.IncidentId});
            }
            }
        </td>
    </tr>
}
```

event when the user is Manager (I can confirm that the RoleProvider works fine, since while debugging I can see how the debugger steps into the code to call Html.ActionLink for the Remove), an actual action link doesn't get rendered into the resulting html?

If I just place

```
@Html.ActionLink("Remove", "Remove", new { id = item.IncidentId })
```

it gets rendered fine.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`@{ }` is a code block, values won't get written to the response output by default.

You could either do:

```
@{
  if (User.IsInRole("Manager"))
  {
     @Html.ActionLink("Remove", "Remove", new {id = item.IncidentId});
  }
}
```

or:

```
@if (User.IsInRole("Manager"))
{
   @Html.ActionLink("Remove", "Remove", new {id = item.IncidentId});
}
```